# Constrain an instance method

Tags: haskell

I want to write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}

data Ord a => S a = ...
toList :: Ord a => S a -> [a]
fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> S a

instance Functor S where
  fmap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> S a -> S b
  fmap f = fromList . fmap f . toList
```

But GHC keeps smacking me down

> Method signature does not match class

Questions:

- Do you know a work-around?
- What problem does this restriction solve?

Comment: ghc warns: -XDatatypeContexts is deprecated: It was widely considered a misfeature, and has been removed from the Haskell language.

Comment: @user5402 Why is that? What would you do instead?

Comment: @MichaelFox A GADT, such as `data S a where S :: Ord a => [a] -> S a`, or whatever your constructors are.

Comment: Check out the paper [*Categorical Programming for Data Types with
Restricted Parametricity*](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~dao29/drafts/tfp-structures-orchard12.pdf) for non-endo-functors in Haskell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, simply.  The `Functor` class is defined such that it must work with all `a -> b`, not just some `a -> b`.  You could define your own `FunctorOrd`, though.

```
class FunctorOrd f where
    fmapOrd :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

However, this may not be what you want.  I'm guessing that you're wanting to build some kind of set-like structure that uses a binary tree internally to maintain uniqueness.  What happens if I were to do something like

```
s :: S Int
s = fromList [1..100]

t :: S Bool
t = fmap even s
```

This would simply apply `even` to every `Int` in the set, it wouldn't be able to alter the structure at all, just what it contains.  You'd be better off writing a function like

```
smap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> S a -> S b
smap f = fromList . map f . toList
```

Or possibly one that is more efficient, but still has the ability to change the structure itself, not just the values.

This isn't a restriction exactly, it's that the `Functor` laws must be satisfied in order for `fmap` to behave properly.  It may not seem like a big deal, but go look up the controversial history of various `ListT` implementations and how they don't all satisfy the monad laws.